# need to trigger a json request from javascript code

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I am working in javascript and need trigger a json request for an array of element contains account number, customer details like address and name to a third part system. Could someone please help me with a sample code

var reqArr = {"accountNum" : "12345",
"custName" : "shahbaz",
"address" : "pune"
};

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery https://jquery.com/

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST', // GET OR POST
    url: '/form/', // YOUR URL
    data: '{"name":"jonas"}', // or JSON.stringify ({name: 'jonas'}),
    success: function(data) { alert('data: ' + data); }, // ON SUCCESS
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
});
```